# sending 2 values in 1 array in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have 2 arrays of data and i need to join the results of this two arrays.

I can use `array_combine` but there is 2 issues:

1. my first array is coming from check boxes and send data of checked check-box only
2. my second array coming from input fields and sending all my inputs

**the issue here is my first array have (for example) 3 values while my second array has 7 values**

This kind of combine will return the error of:

```
array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements
```

## Data

this is my dd results:

```
  "optionID" => array:3 [▼ //check-box values
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
    2 => "11"
  ]
  "optionPRICE" => array:8 [▼ //input values
    0 => "98"
    1 => null
    2 => null
    3 => null
    4 => null
    5 => null
    6 => null
    7 => null
  ]
```

## what I want

what i'm looking for is to get values of my inputs from checked check-boxes and not the rest of them.

example i check data 1,2,3 i get value 1,2,3 whether is `null` of `filled` and not getting 4,5,6,7 as you see in my dd data above.

## code

this is what my html looks like

```
<tr>
  <td class="text-center" width="50">
    <label class="switch switch-small">
      <input type="checkbox" name="optionID[]" value="11"> //checkbox arrays
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </td>
  <td>
    CDN
  </td>
  <td class="text-center">
    //input arrays
    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="optionPRICE[]">
  </td>
</tr>
```

**I'm looking to get my data in any of this 2 kinds**

`this`

```
  "optionID" => array:3 [▼ //check-box values
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
    2 => "11"
  ]
  "optionPRICE" => array:8 [▼ //input values
    0 => "98"
    1 => null
    2 => null
  ]
```

`or this`

```
  "optionID" => array:3 [▼
    "array" => array:2 [
       0 => "1",
       1 => "98",
     ],
     "array" => array:2 [
        0 => "2",
        1 => null,
     ],
     "array" => array:2[
        0 => "11",
        1 => null,
     ],
  ]
```

any idea?

## Update

Based on answers if i use mapping function to return data as my second sample desire it would be confusing to naming data and relate them to my model column, so I share my model names and explain which data has to go in which column in order to be save in right place.

`Schema`

```
Schema::create('product_options', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->integer('product_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
  $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
  $table->integer('option_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
             $table->foreign('option_id')->references('id')->on('options')->onDelete('cascade');
  $table->string('price')->nullable();
});
```

`optionID` data has to go in `option_id` column and `optionPRICE` data to `price` column.

For product_id column as this data will save after my product is saved so i just simply get the id by `$product->id` that column is out of issue.

## Update 2

I tried many different conditions to see how data will send here is a serious issue based on the answers I've got.

When I pass data from 1 selected option, `e.g.` select **colors** and fill some data to send it works as it supposed to.

But when I select second option `e.g.` select **sizes** for this option only checkbox id's will send and data of `optionPRICE` will not send, this issue applies for next options as well (option 3,4,5,6....)

> Here is a sample:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼ //this is from colors (included price)
    "option_id" => "4"
    "price" => "768"
    "product_id" => 50
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼ //this is also from colors (included price)
    "option_id" => "5"
    "price" => "5467"
    "product_id" => 50
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼ //this one is from sizes (not included price, while i filled the price!)
    "option_id" => "10"
    "price" => null
    "product_id" => 50
  ]
]
```

## Update 3

OK, I worked around and tested some ways to fix the issue, here is what i figured and what i achieved:

1. Th issue of returning my third price null (update 2) was because we were counting prices array and not inputs of checked check-boxes. that was why 3rd option was null while my actual filled option was 11. (refer to my data dd top of my question)
2. I can get now actual filled `optionPRICE` fields and not by counting them but with the values.

Here is what I did so far:

```
$options = $request->input('optionID');
$prices = $request->input('optionPRICE');
$collection = array_filter($prices, function($value) {
  return !is_null($value);
});
$toInsert = array_merge([$options, $collection]);
dd($toInsert);
```

code above returns this:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    0 => "4"
    1 => "5"
    2 => "10"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    0 => "768"
    1 => "5467"
    5 => "5465496"
  ]
]
```

but if i fill price for only 2 of my check-boxes will be like:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    0 => "4"
    1 => "5"
    2 => "10"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    0 => "768"
    1 => "5467"
  ]
]
```

This is good to get only input data without needs of counting array elements just pure values.

**After this I need to join this 2 array of mine and return null in case of second case happens (3 check-box, 2 price).**

Any help on that?

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your second desired output. Is it correct or did you mean your second array to be `[2, null]` and third array to be `[11,null]`?

Comment: @Mozammil i just tried to explain that they comes together as 1 array :) either `[11,null]` or `0=>11,1=>null` :))

Comment: Yes, but in your example, the second array has 1 as the first item. Shouldn't that be 11?

Comment: i just made up that to explain is not that it's actual data dd :) don't take it seriously it's just dummy sample

Comment: It would confuse everybody :)

Comment: already edit it

Answer (score 0):

This should get you your first desired solution using [`array_slice`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_slice.asp):

```
// Get the length of the smaller array
$minLength = min(count($arr1), count($arr2));

$result = [
    'optionID' => array_slice($arr1, 0, $minLength),
    'optionPRICE' => array_slice($arr2, 0, $minLength),
];
```

Comment: i'm getting `count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable`

Comment: You have to replace `$arr1` with your optionID array and `$arr2` with your optionPRICE array.

Comment: Well it says that one of those isn't an array. Post your backend code if you want further help

Comment: Replace `->has('input_name')` with `->input('input_name')`. Like this: `$request->input('optionID')` (in all 4 uses)

Comment: as our conversation here http://collabedit.com/gd7ph ,  i tested it it works as you say yes it returns data perfectly but somewhere between foreach and DB::table( it will lose prices data.
when i make dd results are fine like your sample, when i save in db it's less of prices

Answer (score 0):

For your second desired solution, you could try something like this (if I understood correctly):

```
$checkboxes = [1, 2, 11]; 
$inputs = [98, null, null]; 

$result = collect($checkboxes)->map(function ($item, $key) use($inputs) {
    return [$item, $inputs[$key] ?? null]; 
})->toArray();

dd($result);

// array:3 [
//   0 => array:2 [
//     0 => 1
//     1 => 98
//   ]
//   1 => array:2 [
//     0 => 2
//     1 => null
//   ]
//   2 => array:2 [
//     0 => 11
//     1 => null
//   ]
// ]
```

Comment: it returns like `array:1 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    0 => true
    1 => null
  ]
]`

Comment: I don't know if that's possible for OP's use case. But if the `$inputs` is longer than `$checkboxes`, this wouldn't work

Comment: ok here can we add names into the results instead of 0 & 1? so it would be easier to define them for saving in database. currently is like this `0 "1"
1 "434"`

Comment: @devk Hmm, why not? We are mapping over the values of checkboxes and picking up the corresponding price from the inputs array.

Comment: @mafortis Isn't that beyond the scope of your question? :)

Comment: FYI, here's a link to a [working solution](https://implode.io/zb18eH) where inputs array could be any length.

Comment: @Mozammil sorry my mistake. It would break if the `$checkboxes` is longer, not `$inputs`

Comment: @devk again, no.. There's a null coalescing operator in there. You can check it [here](https://implode.io/zb18eH)

Comment: @Mozammil it might be count as beyond my question scope, but trust me if i make new question and say i have all the codes till mapping function but don't know how to save them it gets like 500 vote-down LOL . so please help make it all in one here, i can add new request to my question if that fixes the scope for you :))))

Comment: I don't know the names of your Models. So I can't know how to convert them to "names" -- You might want to edit your original question :)

Comment: Why do you want to convert them to names in the first place? Ultimately you are saving it to your table as Ids?